# git submodules on pull request(s)

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Lets say we have a parent project which contains a submodule.

You are merging something into the child one, and then on the parent repo, when creating a pull request, you want to have all the latest changes made on the child, visible.

How they can be synchronized between them to reflect any change on the child repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not seem to be directly supported ([issue BSERV-4198](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-4198)), which is why you have third-party solutions like [Submodule Changes for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221068/submodule-changes-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview)

It is however not free, but allows for easily review the changes made to Git submodules in the Diff tab in Bitbucket.

[image: https://marketplace-cdn.atlassian.com/files/5fd50c21-29ea-4629-92f3-ed23c841f3c6?fileType=image&mode=full-fit]

Comment: Sadly, paying for 3rd parties is not an option.

Comment: @RaulTrebuian I suspected as much. I was only mentioning this product to illustrate there is no native supported solution.